# Integral of $1/x^2$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that the integral of
$1/x^2$ is $(-1/x +C)$

Can we split $(1/x^2)$ as $(1/x)(1/x)$ and say that the integral of $(1/x^2)$ is $\ln x\cdot\ln x$?

PS: I am new to high school. And this is my first question on Stack Exchange.

Comment: No, the integral of the product is not the product of the integral.

Comment: It's rather obvious that you can't, isn't it? After all, it contradicts what you said in your first sentence.

Comment: What is the derivative of $\ln x \cdot \ln x$? Use the product rule: $(fg)' = f'g + fg'.$

Comment: In general, assume that doing this does not make sense, as that is the norm in mathematics ($(x+y)^2 \ne x^2+y^2, \frac{1}{x+y} \ne \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}, e^{x+y} \ne e^x + e^y$ and so on). The definite integral properties all have nice geometric representations which let you see why they are true.

Comment: Your second approach is wrong, but it's related to [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts). Rather than integrating $\int uv^\prime dx$ as $\int udx$ times $v$, we get $uv-\int u^\prime vdx$.

Comment: Thanks! I calculated the derivative of $1/x^2$ and found that it did not match my expected answer as mentioned by @CalvinKhor and md2perpe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is good to ask no problem. The integral behaves nicely with addition and subtraction , I mean, if $\int f(x) dx$ and $\int g(x)  dx$ exist then $$\int(f(x)+g(x) dx=\int f(x) dx+\int g(x) dx$$ The same for subtraction. But in general , we can NOT say $$\int f(x) g(x) dx=\int f(x) dx \times \int g(x) dx$$
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks...this really helped me understand from a student's point of view.

Comment: You're very  welcome

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to differentiate a product you will know that $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ (where $f'$ is the derivative of $f$). Set $h=f'$ so that $f=\int h dx $.

Then $(fg)'=hg+fg'$ and $$\int hg dx=\int\left((fg)'-fg'\right)dx=fg-\int(fg')dx$$which is the formula for integration by parts.

---

Because I began from the derivative of a product, the notation for integrals gets a bit clunky. zwim in the comments has usefully given a more convenient form, which simply comes from renaming the functions, with $f=F'$:

$$\int fg dx=Fg-\int Fg' dx$$

---

The formula for the derivative of a product is one of its characteristic properties, which gets generalised to derivatives in other contexts. Its form suggests that integration, as the inverse operation, will have a more complicated relationship with the product of functions than you have postulated. But "how does this work with products" - what is the relationship of some operation with the underlying arithmetic - is always a good one to ask.

Comment: I would write $\int fg=Fg-\int Fg'$ instead, with $F'=f$ instead of using $h$ for readability.

Comment: @zwim I have compromised and included that form too. I wanted to keep the derivation from the derivative form, because that was not taught to me properly when I was young.